# How to show full image as background in div with set height and width values

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background for a div with set height and width. The result is that it crops away the parts of the image which is not located where the div is. I want the image to scale down to fit the size of the div.

```html
<div style="width: 512px; height: 288px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom: 1em; background-attachment:fixed; background-position:center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;background-image: url(image url)></div>
```

Comment: Use background-size: cover;

Comment: @Peter That reduces the amount of the image that is shown.

Comment: @SimenEilevstjønn Try to use background picture with width and height same like div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your image to stretch, to fill its container in all directions without cropping, use `background-size: 100% 100%;`. This will distort the image if its container has a different aspect ratio than the image itself.

If you want your image to fill its container in one direction, without cropping and without stretching, use `background-size: contain;`. This may leave unused space on the sides or on the top/bottom if its container has a different aspect ration than the image itself.

If you want your image to fill its container in all directions, cropping as necessary but without stretching, use `background-size: cover;`. This may crop parts of the image off the sides or the top/bottom if its container has a different aspect ratio than the image itself.

This snippet demonstrates the difference between these techniques. In all three cases, a 500x500 image is being put into a 500x250 div.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#stretch-demo {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500');
}

#contain-demo {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500');
}

#cover-demo {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500');
}
```

```html
<div id="stretch-demo"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="contain-demo"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="cover-demo"></div>
```

Here is the full source image:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of how all three techniques should look:

[image]

---

**Addendum**

I notice that you are using `background-attachment: fixed;`.

I assume this is because you want to fill your div with content, and allow the div to have a scrollbar, but avoid having the background image "scroll away" with the content.

For this purpose, you should use `background-attachment: scroll;` instead.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500');
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque
  vitae tempus. Quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Maecenas sed enim ut sem. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus. Tellus orci ac auctor augue. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis.
  Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi. Erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque
  habitant morbi. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc. Leo urna molestie at elementum eu. Interdum varius sit amet mattis. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce
  ut. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Sed vulputate
  odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit. Blandit turpis cursus in hac. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at.
  Risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum
  lorem sed risus. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum.
  Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer. Maecenas
  accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi
  etiam dignissim. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
  et netus. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Morbi quis commodo odio
  aenean. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Massa sed elementum
  tempus egestas sed sed. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. At in tellus integer feugiat. Urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices
  mi tempus imperdiet. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in. Amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut.
</div>
```

Comment: None of these methods show the entire image, but they vary a bit in how much they do show.

Comment: @SimenEilevstjønn methods #1 and #2 should show the entire image. i've added a screenshot of how the example is expected to look. does the screenshot not match what you are seeing? (you can tell they have the full image because you can see the 'powered by html.com' watermark on the bottom edge of the image.)

Comment: My 100% 100% looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/AJ2MKSP.png

Comment: @SimenEilevstjønn based on the fact that you're using `background-attachment: fixed;`, i'm inferring a little bit about what you're trying to do. please take a look at the addendum i've just added -- it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can Resize the image to the size of the container or use background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was that I was using `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: i think you likely want `background-attachment: scroll;` instead, if the div's content is scrollable.